# how to send tweet to non followers?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a site.and i want to tweet to non followers from my site without going to twitter site.
how can do this. Please help me?

Comment: Sending a tweet to non-followers sounds like something Twitter would very deliberately prevent you from doing.

Comment: @bobince Indeed they do.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking how the Direct Message someone who doesn't follow you - that's not possible. From [Twitter's support site](http://help.twitter.com/portal):

> **What are Direct Messages?**
>   Direct messages are private messages sent from one Twitter person to another.  You can only send a direct message to a person who follows you.  When you receive a direct message, we save it in your direct message inbox, accessible from the Direct Message tab in the sidebar in your home page.  Set your email preferences to notify you by mail if you have a new message.

As long as your account isn't 'protected' all your tweets are visible to non-followers. You can simply 'at' them to send a public tweet 'to' them. Just use the [statuses-update REST method](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses%C2%A0update).